# Plot BLE real-time data on the graph

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I recevied the real-time BLE data and I would like to display data on the graph. Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver, makeGattUpdateIntentFilter());
    if (mBluetoothLeService != null) {
        boolean result = mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress0,0);
        boolean result1 = mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress1, 1);
    }

    
    // The Runnable interface should be implemented by any class whose instances are intended
    // to be executed by a thread. The class must define a method of no arguments called run.
    mTimer = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            graphLastXValue += 1.0;
            mSeries0.appendData(new DataPoint(graphLastXValue, getDeviceData0()),true, 150);
            mSeries1.appendData(new DataPoint(graphLastXValue, getDeviceData1()),true, 150);
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1);
        }
    };
    mHandler.postDelayed(mTimer, 100);
}
```

My questions are:

1. What's the function for 2 postDelayed() in the code respectively? In my code, I delayed 200ms in total, right?
2. How to add new BLE data to the graph as soon as new data arrives, instead of using a fixed time period postdelay(), please?